# What is the difference between Type and Type*?

Tags: lean

I have seen some instance of `Type*` in [this project](https://github.com/PatrickMassot/lean-differential-topology/blob/5b020daa5f935140c53408748a9f11ba02e7bf42/src/calculus.lean#L15). Running `#check Type*` gives `Type u_1 : Type (u_1+1)` and `#check Type` gives `Type : Type 1`.

Performing a [search over the language reference](https://leanprover.github.io/reference/search.html?q=Type*) and `Ctrl-F`ing the Expressions chapter doesn't seem to give any information on `Type*`. What, conceptually, is it used for? Also, if possible, what is being used for in the project that I linked?

(The `*` is hard to search for, sorry if this is a duplicate.)

Comment: Is it possible that this is simply a shorthand for introducing a new universe along with a type from that universe? That is, that doing `variable E : Type*` is equivalent to doing `universe u` followed by `variable E : Type u`? (Assuming `u` hasn't been previously used.) I notice that `Sort*` is also a thing.

Comment: BTW, the Lean Zulip chat root would be the place to get a quick answer to this question: it's open to all comers.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for the advice! I'll be sure to check that place out in the near future.

Comment: Gah. chat *room*, not chat root! Stupid fingers. https://leanprover.zulipchat.com